# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.Management.ServiceBus.Fluent'

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, azureservicebus

I am working on Azure service bus from my console application. I have a separate project and I have installed the nuGet package "Microsoft.Azure.Management.ServiceBus.Fluent" package to get connection string using namespace. After installing the package and running the application, I get this exception:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.Management.ServiceBus.Fluent, Version=1.0.0.66, Culture=neutral or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'

How do I resolve it? Please leave it in the comments if I can add any other details.

Comment: `I have a separate project and I have installed the nuGet package`: Is the separate project part of the same Console application solution? If not, you should open the VisualStudio Solution of the "separate project", and install the NuGet from there.

Comment: The projects are part of the same console application's solution. That project does the service bus connection process and that's why I have installed the package there.

Comment: Are you using .NET Framework or .NET Core? If .NET Framework, check in the `App.config` file the `<bindingRedirect />` nodes. Do you see any `Microsoft.Azure.Management.ServiceBus.Fluent` value in there?

Comment: Thanks @Catalin, actually the problem was the path that it was referring was to a different console application. I found this when I expanded the properties section and checked the path and "Copy local" set to neither true nor false.

Comment: @Deepak,did you create a net framework console project or a net core console project? Also, what  version of `Microsoft.Azure.Management.ServiceBus.Fluent` did you install, `1.36.0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First of all**, I assume you have installed **Microsoft.Azure.Management.ServiceBus.Fluent** version `1.36.0`.

**If** your project is net framework with `packages.config` nuget package format, you could try these:

To correct the path, you should clean nuget caches first(delete all files under `C:\Users\xxx\.nuget\packages`) and `packages` folder under the solution folder

then run the below command to correct the path:

```
update-package -reinstall
```

under **Tools**-->**Nuget Package Manager**-->**Package Manager Console**.

**Also**, you could just modify the `csproj` file and change the `hintpath` of the nuget package reference to the right nuget dll path.

```
<Reference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Management.ServiceBus.Fluent, Version=1.0.0.66, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Azure.Management.ServiceBus.Fluent.1.36.0\lib\net452\Microsoft.Azure.Management.ServiceBus.Fluent.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

**Besides**, add `bindingRedirect` might be a safe choice.

Add this under `app.config` file

```
 <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Azure.Management.ServiceBus.Fluent" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.0.0.66" newVersion="1.0.0.66" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

=========================================================

**If** your project is net core project with **PackageRefence** nuget management format,

you should also clean nuget caches first and then delete `bin` and `obj` folder.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you have installed latest version of `Microsoft.Azure.Management.ServiceBus.Fluent`: **1.36.1**. Further, one of your nuget package has a dependency on it's version **1.0.0.66**.

*To resolve this*, you might have to downgrade your package to **1.0.0 version or equivalent**.

Comment: Thanks Singh, but actually the problem was referring to a wrong nuget package path. I've added it in the comment below the question :)

Comment: Okay. Good to know